# iPod Shuffle first gen not mounting, Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: mount, ipod

I have a 1st gen 1GB iPod shuffle (still working well to my surprise). It's the one looking like a Thumb Drive. It's formatted in FAT32 using MBR. Uder MacOS I see two mounted drives, one is like a standard USB drive where I can copy my music, the other device is to manage the iPod. I Use rebuild_db, a python script, to use it without iTunes or Apple Music. I just paste my mp3s in the file browser, launch the python script, and the iPod is ready to play.

Under Windows, I also see it as a USB drive and I can manage files like normal.

I can also see it's content when I plug it on my android phone.

On Ubuntu 20.04, 22.04 and 22.10 (three different PCs), I hear the USB-plug-in sound, but nothing is auto-mounted. If I open the Disk Utility (Palimpsest) I see the drive as unmounted and as un-formatted . It's impossible to mount the drive.

Is there a way I can mount and access the content of the iPod ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out this is a known libgpod bug preventing the mounting of some iPob shuffle models.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libgpod/+bug/565971

un-installing libgpod is a workaround. If you don't use any other iPod it's a safe solution.